# How to write XML Spreadsheet format to clipboard to paste in Excel (javascript)

Tags: javascript, excel, xml, clipboard

I'm trying to put some data in clipboard (by clicking a button on a website), which will be then possible to paste in MS Excel (by Ctrl+V). The data needs to have some specific Excel-formatting, that's why I need to use "XML Spreadsheet" clipboard format, not HTML for example (although I know excel uses many other formats too).

I've tried Clipboard API (`navigator.clipboard.writeText` and `navigator.clipboard.write`) and `document.execCommand('copy')`, but it worked only for HTML, not for XML.
However, not sure which mime type should be used. For "application/xml" Clipboard API throws: "DOMException: Type application/xml not supported on write."

Would prefer to avoid external libraries. `document.execCommand('copy')` is deprecated, so it's probably not a good idea to use it too.

Example XML to put in clipboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1"
   ss:DefaultRowHeight="14.4">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">100</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">200</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">300</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

This is the way I'm trying to achieve this (the code that throws an error for "application/xml" type, but works with HTML):

```
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" >copy data to clipboard</button>

<script >
function myFunction() {
var str = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1"   ss:DefaultRowHeight="14.4">   <Row>    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">100</Data></Cell>    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">200</Data></Cell>    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">300</Data></Cell>   </Row>  </Table> </Worksheet></Workbook>';

var data = [new ClipboardItem({ "application/xml": new Blob([str], { type: "application/xml" }) })];
navigator.clipboard.write(data)
    }
</script>   

</body>
</html>
```

When I use "text/plain" type or `navigator.clipboard.writeText()` clipboard see data as a string and paste text in Excel ("<?xml version..."). Type: "text/html" seems to ignore XML formatting and paste all numbers in one cell.

I have found similar question, but it's not in javascript:
[How do I get OpenXML onto the clipboard so that it will paste into Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614871/how-do-i-get-openxml-onto-the-clipboard-so-that-it-will-paste-into-excel)
Maybe it would help.